# I am getting "Object is possibly null" error when trying to return the count of characters and numbers from a string

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript, function

So, I am trying to return the count of characters and numbers that occur more than once in the input string.

So for instance, if I input `"zzrrcde"`, I would get 2 since `z` and `r` have more than 1.

Below is the function I came up with after researching. I wanted to use regex instead of doing a double loop.  But, I am getting the following error: `TS2531 Object is possibly null.`  Can somebody explain why this error is occurring? I am calling up `text` in the return in this example.

```
export function duplicateCount(text: string): number {
  try{ return text.toLowerCase().split("").sort().join("").match(/(.)\1+/g).length; }
  catch(e){ return 0; }
}

console.log(duplicateCount("aabbcde"))
```

I then tried this example by creating a variable `var newText = text` and I am still getting the same error.

```
export function duplicateCount(text: string): number{
  var newText = text;
  try{ return newText.toLowerCase().split("").sort().join("").match(/(.)\1+/g).length; }
  catch(e){ return 0; }
}

console.log(duplicateCount("aabbcde"))
```

Does anyone know what it is I am doing wrong?  I am learning TypeScript, so any in-depth explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: `.match` can return `null`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a global regex does not match anything in the string, rather than returning an empty array, it'll return `null`. For example, using your code:

```js
function duplicateCount(text) {
  return text.toLowerCase().split("").sort().join("").match(/(.)\1+/g).length;
}

console.log(duplicateCount("abc"))
```

Better not to use `try`/`catch` for ordinary expected control flow anyway, especially in TypeScript - test if the match exists first. Reserve the catching of errors for *unexpected* things like when an asynchronous API fails.

```
const match = text.toLowerCase().split("").sort().join("").match(/(.)\1+/g);
return match ? match.length : 0;
```

You could also reduce the computational complexity by removing the `.sort` (`O(n log n)`) and instead iterate over the characters one by one:

```
export function duplicateCount(text: string) {
    const countByChar: { [char: string]: number } = {};
    for (const char of text) {
        countByChar[char] = (countByChar[char] || 0) + 1;
    }
    return Object.values(countByChar)
        .filter(val => val >= 2)
        .length;
}
```

Comment: @CertainPerformace Thank you! Can you explain what const countByChar: { [char: string]: number } = {} is doing?  
Is countByChar a new object which takes in a character that has the type set to string and is returning a number?

Comment: It indicates that the new object has keys which are strings, and values are numbers. For example, the current typing would forbid `countByChar[char] = (countByChar[char] || '') + 'x'` because that would be assigning a value which is a string where a number is required.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a default value in case your match is null.

```
export function duplicateCount(text: string): number {
  try {
    return text.toLowerCase().split("").sort().join("").match(/(.)\1+/g)?.length || 0;
  }
  catch (e) {
    return 0;
  }
}

console.log(duplicateCount("aabbcde"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need `try` ?

```js
function duplicateCount(text) {
  if (!text) return 0;
  let matchedArray = text.toLowerCase().split("").sort().join("").match(/(.)\1+/g);
  return matchedArray ? matchedArray.length : 0;
}

console.log(duplicateCount("aabbcde"))
console.log(duplicateCount("abcdee"))
console.log(duplicateCount(""))
```